# How can i use filter instead of forEach (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, filter

I have the below function. i am using forEach. how can i use filter instead of using forEach in my function. i searched online but couldnt find a way to achieve this.

```
pendingPaymentsUtils.getPendingPayment = paymentId => {
  const payments = pendingPaymentsUtils.getPendingPayments()
  let payment = {}

  payments.forEach(function(_payment) {
    if (_payment.id === paymentId) {
      payment = _payment
      return false
    }
  })

  return payment
}
```

I have tried the follow way but it isnt working as expected.

```
pendingPaymentsUtils.getPendingPayment = paymentId => {
  const payments = pendingPaymentsUtils.getPendingPayments()
  let payment = {}

  payments.filter(function(_payment) {
      payment = _payment
      return _payment.id === paymentId ? false: true
  })

  return payment
}
```

Comment: what effort have you made to refactoring it?

Comment: Does the `forEach` approach work? It looks like it only returns the last item that matches the criteria. Do you want to return all the items that match the criteria or only the last one?

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you just replaced the text "forEach" with "filter", it would result in the same return value for payment. forEach and filter run once for every item within the array (payments in your case). The difference is that filter will return a subset array of every value that return true within the filter/forEach function, while forEach doesn't return anything.

Comment: @DanielA.White- thanks. updated my refactored code.

Comment: @ashwinprabhu Are you only expecting to find one item in the array?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir- There is a test case for it and its failing when i use your solution. 
Expected: {"id": "payment1"}----- 
Received: [{"id": "payment1"}]---- so i am receiving as a array i guess?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir- In the earlier implementation if a payment is not found, an empty object is returned. In the new implementation undefined will be returned. How to corrrect that case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `filter` returns an array of results, so just return that and get rid of the `payment` variable.
2. `_payment.id === paymentId ? false: true` could be shortened to just `return _payment.id === paymentId;`
3. Use implicit returns of arrow functions to shorten this even more.
4. By the looks of things it seems that what you need is [**`find`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of [**`filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Something like this:

```
pendingPaymentsUtils.getPendingPayment = paymentId => {
  const payments = pendingPaymentsUtils.getPendingPayments();
  return payments.find(payment => payment.id === paymentId);
}
```

Even shorter if you get rid of the redundant `payments` variable:

```
pendingPaymentsUtils.getPendingPayment = paymentId =>
  pendingPaymentsUtils.getPendingPayments().find(payment => payment.id === paymentId);
```

**Edit:**

To return an empty object instead of `undefined` if no object is found:

```
pendingPaymentsUtils.getPendingPayment = paymentId =>
  pendingPaymentsUtils.getPendingPayments().find(payment => payment.id === paymentId) || {};
```

Comment: mahir- There is a test case for it and its failing when i use your solution. 
Expected: {"id": "payment1"}----- 
Received: [{"id": "payment1"}]---- so i am receiving as a array i guess

Comment: @ashwinprabhu as I suspected, you need `find` not `filter`. `find` returns the first object that matches the criteria where `filter` returns an array of all the items that matched the criteria. I've updated the answer to use `find` instead of `filter`

Comment: In the earlier implementation if a payment is not found, an empty object is returned. In the new implementation undefined will be returned. How to corrrect that case ?

Comment: @ashwinprabhu The return of `undefined` or `null` if no object is found is the standard way, but if your usecase requires an empty object then just add `|| {}` at the end, that way if `find` returns `undefined` (a falsy value), the empty object `{}` will be returned instead. Please check the updated answer.